# Hypeledger Network Data

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been developing blockchain applications using hypeledger fabric for the past 6 months and surprisingly I have used up about 15TB of network data. I do watch a lot of videos but 15TB is a lot, and this has never happened before. I use Ubuntu running on Oracle Virtual Box. My question is what does hypeledger composer rest server do in the background, I am aware that the playground and rest server do not work without internet connection hence why I am asking this question.

Comment: if you're running the REST server on 127.0.0.1 then it will only use that interface (same applies for playground, which can be using the web connector or connecting to localhost fabric). You can easily check your throughput by interface (local, virtual interface, network interface) anyway with networking tools.

Comment: Try to run tcpdump in the background and output it to a log and see what takes up most of the bandwidth